# Error:unresolved external symbol _popen

Tags: c

Why does using popen result in Error: Failed to close command stream under windows?

Comment: Your code has bigger problems than just `_popen` being missing...

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - that was about as useful as a chocolate fireguard

Comment: So is running `ps` on Windows.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - and checkmate, feel good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to use: _popen and _pclose  (yes WITH the silly underscore) under Windows.

See [MSDN Entry on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx); it has a nice example

Now as for _popening "ps" you know whether or not you have a ps on your system.

Comment: as an aside _pclose only needs to be called if you wish to terminate the pipe in the middle of a read. You don't need to do that for what you are showing. All you need to do is feof(pf) { fgets(); }  ...  and read to the end (read the example at the end of MSDN entry)

Comment: I tried with the example on the MSDN page you cited, it works perfectly from command line, but not from the website(cgi)(the cmd prompt flashes(website running on local machine), but the display is internal server error, do you know why? if I comment out all of the lines and just printf("test"); it displays on screen so I know my cgi configuration is ok.